# How can I access several tables sequentially with node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have to access several tables from a database using node js and add the results to an array.  However, I cannot figure out how to access the tables sequentially as node runs ahead asynchronously.  I need to save the results of one table before I can access the next.  Below is an example of how I access the database for reach tables.

```
    function gettable1 (id, cb) {
    table1.getData1(connection, id, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    myArray += data.response;    
    cb();
    });  
    }

    function gettable2(id, cb) {
    table2.getData2(connection, id, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    myArray += data.response;    
    cb();
    });  
    }
     ... etc.
    function gettable5(id, cb) {
    table5.getData5(connection, id, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    myArray += data.response;    
    cb();
    });  
    }

     gettable1(id, callback);
     gettable2(id, callback);
     ....
     gettable5(id, callback);

     return myArray;
```

So how can I make sure that the call to gettable1 is done before I execute gettable2?  The variable myArray is returned before any of the table calls are done.  The asynchronous processing in node really has me stumped and I appreciate any feedback as to how to code my logic to make the tables processing sequentially rather than asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can either nest the callbacks:

```
sql.query(myQuery, function() {
  sql.query(myNextQuery, function() {
    // etc....
```

Or (I recommend) use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: I think I have tried this but the problem is that I have to be able to know which one will finish last so I know that I can then return my array.  I will try it again and thanks to everyone's feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the callbacks if you want them to be sequential.

```
gettable1(id, function(){
    gettable2(id, function(){
        gettable3(id, function(){
           // got all tables
        });
    });
});
```

Of course, the code gets a bit ugly if there are too many levels and there are dozens of ways to make it look better with various tradeoffs.

Comment: Sorry to say that nesting the callback's didn't work either.  The problem is trying to not prematurely end the nested functions.  My last function is merely to return the array but it gets returned before the callbacks are completed.  So how do I prevent the last noncallback function, which pulls everything together, from executing before the table callbacks are completed?

Comment: what do you mean prematurely end? One of the functions getting an error and going to the `if(err)` branch?

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise in your case. Create Promise fr each function call and Use

```
Promise1.then(function(result){
   Promise2.then(function(result){
      ....
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Perhaps tying in the names of my functions in your example?  I have used promise in angular jscript but not in node. Is it the same?